# update jenkins declarative job without building

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have some jobs that are being configured using a GitHub Organisation. This all works fine. Some of these jobs should only run on `cron` triggers, not on every commit to the repository.

My problem is, how can I change the triggers without actually building the job. If I modify the Jenkinsfile and push it to the repo, I can config Jenkins to either build it or not.
But if I don't want to build it on commit, I also don't seem to get any new config from my Jenkinsfile, like new `cron` triggers.

So how can I reconfigure `cron` triggers without actually running the job?

Answer (score 0):

In the scripts triggered by Jenkins, you could [list the files modified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40555250/6309)

```
git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT
```

If the only modified file is the Jenkisfile, you could consider *not* running the [next step, using a condition (`when`)](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to separate the Jenkinsfile to a separate repository than the code itself.

Another option is to have a upstream Jenkinsfile (which have only the cron trigger and activates the downstream job) and a downstream Jenkinsfile which resides in different repositories.