# How to get changed files list in git using jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a git repo. I need to get the changed files in json format or any file format, when the Jenkins build is done

Comment: While these do not provide a concrete answer to your question, you can have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979573/how-to-find-out-list-of-all-changed-files-in-git-for-full-jenkins-build-and-not) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260383/how-to-get-list-of-changed-files-since-last-build-in-jenkins-hudson/39862273).

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this:
`git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT` in your build script, pipe it to a file and you should have the list of all the files that have changed in that particular build.
This is assuming you are using the [Git Plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).

> The git plugin sets several environment variables you can use in your
>   scripts:
>
> GIT_COMMIT - SHA of the current GIT_BRANCH - Name of the remote
>   repository (defaults to origin), followed by name of the branch
>   currently being used, e.g. "origin/master" or "origin/foo"
>
> GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH - Name of the branch on Jenkins. When the "checkout
>   to specific local branch" behavior is configured, the variable is
>   published.  If the behavior is configured as null or **, the property
>   will contain the resulting local branch name sans the remote name.
>
> GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT - SHA of the previous built commit from the same
>   branch (not set on first build on a branch)

If you want this file to be a build artifact, you can use the Archive Artifacts post build step.

Comment: for first build $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT will not be available, How to proceed in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt email template which will send you the list for file changes in the current build.

```
post {
  always {
    emailext body: ''
    '${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}'
    '',
    subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Successful",
      mimeType: 'text/html', to: "email list"
  }
}
```

If you want the changes in separate file you can modify the [groovy-html.template](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.templatehttps://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template) as per your requirement